# First line on a jlist already selected

Tags: swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

After some research on the net, I have not really found a complete answer to my question here: I have a JList and I want that when I run my application, the first line is already selected .. like this, at least one item is selected to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
is there a sample of code:

```
modelListNames = new CultureAtListModel();
listNames = new JList<String>();
listNames.setName("name");
scrollPaneN.setViewportView(listNames);
listNames.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 110));
listNames.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
listNames.setSelectedIndex(0);
listNames.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
listNames.setVisibleRowCount(10);
```

Need there a ListCellRenderer?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Just use `setSelectedIndex(0)` when you have populated the list. The need for custom cell renderer depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank for your answer... but that doen't work... I need the first line of the list is selected in case of user don't selects a line which causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Do you mean the first line needs to be selected *always* if the user deselects everything in the list?

Comment: Yes it is... that's what I would do

Comment: You need to be more specific about your requirements. The default selection mode for JList has that behaviour (when combined with setSelectedList(0) after filling it, something is always selected). Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) displaying the problem you have, and precise description of the problem and desired behaviour.

Comment: the error (most probably, not seeing it forces me to guess) is in the code that _uses_ the selection: it has to cope with the case that nothing is selected ..